# Magento 2 : Wrong Increment Id generate in table

Tags: magento2

When I create any entry in admin like product or custom module entry then table assigns +3 increment ids like 1,3,6,9....1569,1572 & so on...

Is there any setting ? I need to do to assign it in sequence way like 1,2,3,...

Any idea? please share.

Comment: What the reason to have such sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the reason for this is that Db configured for replication. Verify MySQL setting auto_increment_increment (sql:  show global variables like 'auto_increment_increment') I believe it configured as 3.